# 2D-Arrays Java coding finding the array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I just saw this code on the web and can't think of what array of 'b' would be.

```
int[][] a = {{4,2},{3,6,8}};
int[] b = a[1]
b[0] = 5;
```

Comment: a[0] = {4,2} and a[1] = {3,6,8}. You are assigning a[1] to b. So b would be {3,6,8}.

Comment: What do you mean, you *can't think of what array of 'b' would be*? You don't know what is the type of `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The int array a is a 2D array which consists of two 1-D arrays: `[4,2]` and `[3,6,8]`.

We have then initialised a 1D array referred to as 'b' which has been set to the second (1-index)  array  of a.

Therefore `b = [3,6,8]`. 'b' refers to the first 1D array in 'a'.

You finally set the 0th index of b's array to be 5. `b[0]=5`

This means b has now become `b=[5,6,8]`

Answer (score 3):

Array a is made up of multiple arrays

```
a[0] = {4,2};
a[1] = {3,6,8};
```

Array b is made up of the second value within array a,

```
int[][] a = {{4,2},{3,6,8}};
int[]   b = {3,6,8};
```

b[0] would be the first element within array b, which in this case replaces 3.

```
b[0] = 5; //b = {5,6,8}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, a two dimensional array has both a `row` and a `column`

In this case, `a[1]` is asking for the second row of `a`. Remember that index begins at `0`.

So, the second row of `a` would be `{3,6,8}`.

Therefore `b = a[1]` evaluates to `b = {3,6,8}`

Then, `b[0]` is accessing the first index of `b`, which is `3` and changing it to `5`. So the end result is `{5,6,8}`.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a 2 dimensional array as an array of arrays.

`a[0]` is `[4,2]`

`a[1]` is `[3,6,8]`

So if you assign `a[1]` to `b`, `b` becomes `[3,6,8]`. Once you assign `5` to `b[0]`, `b` becomes `[5,6,8]`

Answer (score 0):

a is a two dimension array,
Inorder to access a case in that array you need two index variables,..think of it as matrix... There is line and column to store the variables or you can think of ot like array of arrays.. So at first b = {3,6,8} because a[1]  is the second array, then you modified the forst element in b,  so b ={5,6,8}